# How to display random posts in one single category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to be able to randomize the posts in one single category. I have the following code at the moment in functions.php:

```
    <?php

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'generate_random_category_posts', 100 );
function generate_random_category_posts( $query ) {
    $catto = get_queried_object();
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() && $catto->term_id = 9 ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}

?>
```

But the problem is that it randomizes posts in all the categories. Can someone please help me with this and tell me how I can randomize posts only in category number 9?

Comment: Are you working with category or custom taxonomy with terms?

Comment: If is the category try this:

query_posts(array(
  'orderby' => 'rand', 
  'cat' => 9, 
  'posts_per_page' => 1
));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an assignment operator `$catto->term_id = 9` in your conditional instead of a conditional operator like so: `$catto->term_id === 9`.

Help you avoid these mistakes, [yoda conditions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) will...

Comment: wow, now it's working. I am deeply ashamed for the mistake and hope I will not be so stupid in my future questions. Thank you very much for showing me the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can display posts from this category with two different ways write category name

```
<?php
   // write category name that you will display it
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '5' ,'category_name'=>'your_category_name') );
                                    // output the random post
                                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
                                       <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail();
                                            ?>
                                       </a>
                                       <h3><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php echo limit_word_count(the_title()); ?></a></h3>
                                    <div class="meta-post">
                                        <a href="<?php echo the_author_link(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_author(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <em></em>
                                        <span>
                                            <?php echo get_the_date('d M Y');  ?>
                                        </span>

                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

Second way write category id for more information open this link [random posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087599/how-to-show-random-post-type-and-category-wordpress) if you want display random posts from functions.php view the link [random posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20303/function-to-show-random-posts-from-a-category)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the problem with a custom loop is the question of pagination. Can you show me any sample code of how to use pagination with a custom loop?